# Issue with passing parameter to Jasper reports

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have defined the following template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE jasperReport
        PUBLIC "-//JasperReports//DTD Report Design//EN"
        "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/dtds/jasperreport.dtd">

<jasperReport name="HelloJasper_report">
    <parameter name="customer" class="com.eternity.model.Customer"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="20">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="220" y="0" width="200" height="20"/>
                <text><![CDATA[$P{customer.firstName}]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

I am crateing the report with the following:

```
try{
    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    parameters.put("customer", new Customer("Example name"));

    System.out.println("Generating PDF...");
    JasperReport jasperReport =
            JasperCompileManager.compileReport("hellojasper.jrxml");
    JasperPrint jasperPrint =
            JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, new JREmptyDataSource());
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(
            jasperPrint, "HelloJasper.pdf");

    System.out.println("HelloJasper.pdf has been generated!");
}
catch (JRException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

where Customer is

```
public class Customer{

    private String firstName;

    public Customer(String firstName){
        this.firstName = firstName;
   }

}
```

However, the generated PDF just prints:

```
$P{customer.firstName}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, in your report you've declared a `staticText` block, which will print exactly the value from the `text` tag - that is why you're getting `$P{person.firstName}`.

In order to evaluate parameter and print it's value you should use `textField` with `textFieldExpression` in your report design:

```
<textField isBlankWhenNull = "true">
    <reportElement x="220" y="0" width="200" height="20"/>
    <textElement/>
    <textFieldExpression class = "java.lang.String">
        <![CDATA[$P{person}.firstName]]>
    </textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Secondly, you declared your `person` parameter to be an instance of class `com.eternity.model.Person`. Though in code you put `Customer` as a `person` parameter (and it doesn't seem to be a sublclass of Person). You have to:

1. either make your `Customer` a subclass of `com.eternity.model.Person`,
2. or change in your report design `person` parameter to be of class `Customer` with fully qualified package name (there is no package visible in your original answer).

And lastly: the `firstName` field has private modifier, so you should add a public `getFirstName` method to your class

```
public String getFirstName() {
    return this.firstName;
}
```

and then call `<![CDATA[$P{person}.getFirstName()]]>` in your report.

Comment: I've corrected Customer and Person errors I've made in this topic - however, they were correct in the code. I've tried your textFieldExpression, however, I got the following error:

 1. Parameter not found : customer.firstName

Comment: @uksz edited my answer, misplaced curly brace in report. Also take a look at third point in my answer: have you added a public getter method?

Comment: Yes! it works now!! Thanks so much! Now I need to generate table :)  Can you suggest me any documents to read?

Comment: @uksz You're welcome! Just read the documentation on jasper reports or google tutorials / find similar questions here at SO and try it yourself. Good luck!